# How to maintain decimal point rounding of export_summs in a R Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I'm generating linear regression models (`lm()`) with a Shiny app using the user's input. I would like to report the model with `export_summs()` from `jtools` (an excellent tool if you haven't used it! - also check out plot_summs).

**My problem is the decimal points are no longer rounded in the output table, and I can't fix it.**

I tried the argument `export_summs(number_format = "%.2f")` as the docs mention that:

> You can also pass any argument accepted by the huxtable::huxreg()
>   function.

However, this didn't change anything. I also tried to round numeric columns with `sprintf`, which also didn't change anything.

A second problem, the column title "Model 1" is also repeated over 2 rows.

### Example

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(jtools)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(
        width = 350
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        tableOutput("export_summ")
    )

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$export_summ <- renderTable({
        lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris) %>%
            export_summs(number_format = "%.2f") %>%
            mutate_if(is.numeric, list(~sprintf("%.2f", .)))
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

### Expected output (per the console output)

```
─────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                 Model 1         
                        ─────────────────────────
  (Intercept)                          5.01 ***  
                                      (0.07)     
  Speciesversicolor                    0.93 ***  
                                      (0.10)     
  Speciesvirginica                     1.58 ***  
                                      (0.10)     
                        ─────────────────────────
  N                                  150         
  R2                                   0.62      
─────────────────────────────────────────────────
  *** p < 0.001; ** p < 0.01; * p < 0.05.        

Column names: names, Model 1
```

### Actual output

```
names               Model 1
                    Model 1
(Intercept)         5.006 ***
                    (0.0728022201948961)
Speciesversicolor   0.930000000000001 ***
                    (0.102957887170494)
Speciesvirginica    1.582 ***
                    (0.102957887170494)
N                   150
R2                  0.618705730738487
** p < 0.001; * p < 0.01; p < 0.05.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i guess Shiny can't handle the object class created by the huxtable-library.
I suggest using `renderUI()` and `huxtable::to_html()` and then displaying it as regular html-code.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(jtools)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 350
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    uiOutput("export_summ")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$export_summ <- renderUI({
    data<-lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris) %>%
      export_summs(number_format = "%.2f") 
     HTML(huxtable::to_html(data))
   })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

For me it then looks like this:
[image]

Comment: I was looking for this in a slightly different context where I was trying to render a huxtable object in a shiny Rmd report and your suggestion was very helpful. Thank you!